# Запятая перед «либо»

Tags: запятые

Нужна запятая?

`Во втором случае я к вам домой прихожу(,) либо вы сами ко мне домой приходите.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Зависит от решения автора. Если *во втором случае* — это член и второго предложения (*вы сами ко мне домой приходите*), то запятые не нужны:

***Во втором случае я к вам домой прихожу либо вы сами ко мне домой приходите***.

---

Если же автор решит *во втором случае* не относить ко второй части предложения, то запятая нужна:

***Во втором случае я к вам домой прихожу, либо вы сами ко мне домой приходите***.

---

Зависит от того, считает ли автор *во втором случае* общим членом предложения или нет.